# Rewrite rules to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my website on a subfolder

```
/application
/application/php  (all php files)
/application/view (my templates files)
/application/admin (my admin)
```

on my .htaccess i have this condiction to the main files

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?([0-9]*)\/?$ application/php/index.php
```

my website work perfect

```
www.mysite.com/
```

now i want to rewrite rules for the admin folder

```
www.mysite.com/admin  read /application/admin/
```

i tried something like this but dont work

```
RewriteRule admin/^(.+)\/?([0-9]*)\/?$ application/admin/index.php
```

My FUll .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(css|js|xml|swf|flv|pdf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !cron.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !ajax.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/template/(.*)\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/application/inc/OAuth(.*)\.php


RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?([0-9]*)\/?$ application/php/index.php
#RewriteRule admin/^(.+)\/?([0-9]*)\/?$ application/admin/index.php  (not work)


 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
    FileETag None
 </FilesMatch>
 <FilesMatch "\.(xml|php)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 minutes"
    FileETag None
 </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava i m try to have mysite.com/admin/?pag=xxxx&a=yyy  like i said my admin folder r inside application folder

Comment: ok can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: i have edited with full .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin/assets(?:/.*)?$ application/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin(?:/.*)?$ application/admin/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(css|js|xml|swf|flv|pdf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.+)\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|svg)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !cron.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !ajax.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !sitemap.xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/template/(.*)\.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/application/inc/OAuth(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?([0-9]*)/?$ application/php/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava this works, i just get problem with relative path to assets folder. like  application/admin/assets/css   how i can make to not use href="/application/admin/assets and use like /admin/assets or /assets

Comment: Works perfect, there is just one last error, if i go mysite/admin dont work, i need to add slash or /index.php.

Comment: Not really. like, if i access without slash then i get problem with assets folder path. Also assets/images/  wont get correct path to show up with and without slash, i cant figure out what is wrong.